# Broadcasting hostname and IP address

Tags: broadcast

In order to notify all computers within the same [LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) about my existence, I want to broadcast my hostname and IP address.

How do I go about doing so without sending them as a string?

Comment: What do you want to send them _as_? The host name _is_ a string.

Comment: I am pretty much clueless here..Is there any way that it can be sent and ensuring that there requires no conversion at the receiver end?

Comment: Well what I mean is that hostname will be of type string and ipddress will be of type System.net.ipaddress.
Is there anyway they can be sent as their original type without requiring them to be converted to any intermediate form?

Comment: have you thought about sending a UDP broadcast?

Comment: Just to confirm, If i just send the hostname to all other computers on lan. Any person can send messages to me, if required.All they need is to use 'gethostaddress' to obtain the ip-addrress.
Am I going the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Avik, this is what DNS is meant to be used for. While "regular" DNS is meant to hold names and IP addresses for each machine (statically configured), there is a dynamic DNS protocol which allows machines to update their DNS entries in real time.

This sort of capability is used in some of the office environments for my clients where printers on a machine are shared but the machines they're attached to use DHCP (meaning their IP address can change).

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows2000/en/advanced/help/sag_DHCP_imp_InteroperabilityDNS.htm) for details and the Windows implementation with DHCP.

Lets call your machine that wants to advertise itself the SERVER and all the machines that can use it, the CLIENTS.

Of course, dynamic DNS only notifies DNS itself of the name/IP mapping and is useful if the CLIENTS are already aware of your SERVER so they can get the IP address from DNS. If you have no way for CLIENTS to discover that your SERVER has just been added, you'll still need to broadcast a packet occasionally indicating that your SERVER exists (this will only need the SERVER name since CLIENTS will use DNS to get the IP address).

This broadcast packet should be picked up by all CLIENTS and kept in a local table. If the communications from a CLIENT to your SERVER fails, the local table entry for your SERVER should be removed (it'll be re-added when your SERVER broadcasts again).

Answer (score 2):

Basically re-inventing [NetBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) or [ZeroConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf), as popular with small embedded devices for discovery by a Windows or OS X based installer or setup utility.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [UPnP Discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#Discovery).